# Remove write protection in windows

Tags: windows-7

Why do I always get "Cannot write please remove the write protection" when I copy files on C:?  I selected that my account have full control, but I still get this error.  What can I do?

Comment: What are you writing? Where are you writing it to? What are the permissions on that file/directory?

Comment: I am trying to copy from E:\ to C:\. All permisions are set

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wasn't this a pre-RTM bug of Windows 7?